# Taking inputs if number of inputs is not known

Tags: c++

I wish to take inputs from console where the number of inputs are not known. All i know is that they are less then or equal to 10.

I wrote this code but it evaluates the last value twice.

```
int x;
    do{
        cin>>x;
        cout<<check(x)<<"\n";
    }while(std::cin);
```

The inputs are in this form:

```
12 
2 
45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LightnessRacesinOrbit commented, it's [`while(!eof)` bug again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). You should check the stream state *after* reading from it, not *before*.

You can use `cin>>x` in the `while`-condition and apply a special value (i.e. anything not a number) as the end flag like this:

```
while (cin >> x)
{
    // got a value
}
```

Comment: This scheme requires a sentinel value though, because `cin` will hang after the last value waiting for the user to type something.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: actually, the sentinel value could be anything else that is not a number (in which case your original solution worked), however it's unclear in the OP case whether there *is* anything at all sent after the list or we risk just hanging there.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Forgotten this. Updated. Many thanks. :)

Comment: Traditionally, one sends EOF (with e.g. ^D) to signify end-of-input. What's wrong with that here? Alternatively simply break on the 10th iteration.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `^D` certainly seems the way to go, it just must be considered.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, `^D` will end the input. However, OP's code will still print last value twice (one more time after `^D`). Is this because `cin>>` leaves a newline?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: No, it's because his loop is incorrect. He checks the stream state _before_ reading from it, not _after_. It's the daily `while (!eof)` bug again. Your fix is correct.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You awaken me. Update the answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use  istream::geline.

```
char input[1024]
std::cin.getline (input,1024);
```

After you read the line, you have to split it by white-spaces as delimiter. Just ignore 11th split onwards. And you may apply atoi or similar functions on the splits (some_split.c_str()) to get the numeric values

Comment: Note that the OP's example had multiple lines.